# Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Stream 11 laptop won't connect to wifi

Tags: 18.04, wireless, hp

It tries to connect, and then says it failed.

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17185  bytes 1222073 (1.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17185  bytes 1222073 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU. Please provide more details in your question. Review [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Please run `sudo ifconfig` from a terminal and post the results here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will identify your Wi-Fi hardware. There's no point in running the command suggested in the previous comment if the Wi-Fi is missing drivers or is disabled.